# Displaying the key of array, after json encoding in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

So this is my code using php, after doing some query and fetching

Never mind the query method, here is the fetch:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6))
{
    $json_array6["spams"] = $row;
}
```

Then i want to add a new array element with key and value:

```
$arrnew["is_spam_by_me"] = false;
array_push($json_array6["spams"], $arrnew["is_spam_by_me"]);
```

Then later i will use json_encode of some merged array including this one (Just using this for example). Then the json value i got is:

> "spams":{"total":"0","0":false}

The "total" key comes from the query, it's not a problem, the "0" key is the problem.

While what i want to be displayed is:

> "spams":{"total":"0","is_spam_by_me":false}

Where did my code go wrong? Sorry for the long explanation

Comment: You are overwriting `$json_array6["spams"]` on each iteration in your `while`-loop, so it will only contain the last row.

Comment: The array_push is what creates the "0" index. You should use `$json_array6['spams']['is_spam_by_me']=$arrnew['is_spam_by_me'];` instead.

Comment: Just to check - as this looks like a total, do you expect there to be only 1 row anyway?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson should i not use the while loop then? I just figured out that i don't need the while loop :S

Comment: @Nick wow this solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @NigelRen just for this particular query, yes i expect there will be only 1 row. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

```
$json_array6[]["spams"] = $row;
```

try this. In your while you keep putting `$row` value in the  `$json_array6["spams"]` field. Using the above approach you will create a multidimensional array so you can store all your values with the key you want in it. Remember that every array key is unique so if you want the same key name you need to make a new array inside of the array (nested array).

So the issue in your code is that in your array you are creating you only left with the last fetched object from your query as you are overwriting the array field inside your while.

Of course now that you have a multidimensional array you can access it using a `foreach` loop and inside of it you can add the extra array fields you need.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the multidimensional array, got my problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the value to the array directly, so instead of

```
$arrnew["is_spam_by_me"] = false;
```

set it like this...

```
$json_array6["spams"]["is_spam_by_me"] = false;
```

But as noted in the comments, this will just create 1 result as your loop continually overwrites the same value.

The reason why you end up with the result you have is that in...

```
array_push($json_array6["spams"], $arrnew["is_spam_by_me"]);
```

your adding the value of `$arrnew["is_spam_by_me"]` which is `false` to the array, you could use `array_merge()` instead, but the above would be easier.

**Edit:**
Just looking at your result, if you don't need to loop - i.e. as it looks as though your fetching a total (count in this case) rather than a set of results, then you don't need the loop at all!

```
$json_array6["spams"] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6);
$json_array6["spams"]["is_spam_by_me"] = false;
```

Comment: Yeah i just figured that array_push is the one causing the problem. Thanks for helping it solved the problem!